# iterate over multiple csv files in different directories and combine dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a couple of .txt files  in different directories, and want to combine them all into one pandas dataframe per directory.

In this project, I have 51 subjects, from them I extract 52 statistic files (.txt) for each brain region in every subject I am studying.

Please check the directories below:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Lmd8R8EUn2I2oaXn3xeGBwbHl7BWe9sy?usp=sharing

The data is organized according to brain regions, each directory is a brain region.
When you open a directory, you see a subject_id_region_stat.txt file which is organized like this:

```
number of tracts    13369
mean length(mm) 52.697
span(mm)    31.4194
curl    1.67721
elongation  3.99201
diameter(mm)    13.2006
volume(mm^3)    7212.12
trunk volume(mm^3)  5582.88
branch volume(mm^3) 1629.25
total surface area(mm^2)    21133.8
total radius of end regions(mm) 29.6348
total area of end regions(mm^2) 1619.5
irregularity    9.67046
area of end region 1(mm^2)  909
radius of end region 1(mm)  14.8108
irregularity of end region 1    0.758125
area of end region 2(mm^2)  710.5
radius of end region 2(mm)  14.824
irregularity of end region 2    0.971672
qa  0.202616
nqa 0.252599
dti_fa  0.327338
md  0.555428
ad  0.753266
rd  0.456509
gfa 0.0998377
iso 0.418337
rdi 0.523584
nrdi02L 0.352668
nrdi04L 0.050425
nrdi06L 0
```

Each directory has 51 .txt files for each subject I am studying.

What I want to do:

---

**Objective 1**-create a pandas dataframe for each directory, where every row is subject id and column names are the indexes in "stat.txt" file. (lets call it a region dataframe)

---

**Objective 2**-Create a dataframe to store descriptive statistics of each region dataframe, for the same column in each region dataframe and save descriptive statistics for each brain region in one pandas dataframe (for example, I want to create a dataframe called "number of tracts" which has descriptive statistics as rows and region names as columns.

Here is the python code I wrote for that.

---

Code for objective 1:

```
directory = "/content/drive/MyDrive/brain-mapping-mega-project/data"
df_concat=pd.DataFrame()
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for subdirectory in subdirectories:
        path=(os.path.join(root, subdirectory))
          # loop over the list of csv files
        csv_files=[] 
        csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))
        df=pd.DataFrame()
        for f in range(len(csv_files)):      
           # read the csv file
          df = pd.read_csv(csv_files[f], sep='\t', index_col=0, header=None, names=[str(f)])
          ser1 = df.iloc[:,0]
          df_concat=pd.concat([df_concat,ser1], axis=1)
          df_concat_transposed=df_concat.transpose()
          name=str(os.path.basename(path))
          df_concat_transposed.to_csv(name+".csv")
```

---

Code for objective 2:

```
directory = "/content/drive/MyDrive/brain-mapping-mega-project/data/data_frames"

df_agg=pd.DataFrame()
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  df= pd.read_csv(filename)
    descriptive=df.describe()
  my_ser = descriptive['number of tracts']
  my_ser.rename(PurePath(filename).stem, inplace = True)
  df_agg=pd.concat([df_agg,my_ser], axis=1)
```

My problem is that I get a dataframe with descriptive statistics as rows and region names as columns, but the values are the same.

I figured out the error is with in the code I wrote for the first objective, but could find a way to correct it.

Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks a lot!